# SSE not working as expected on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, server-sent-events

It is the first time for me working with **Server Sent Events** and probably I'm doing something wrong... I just followed a few guides and doing code experiments and locally everything seems to work fine.

Unfortunately when I upload the app on **Heroku** it doesn't work as expected.

The Javascript looks like this:

```
// SSE Start
// Check if SSE is supported
if (!!window.EventSource) {
  var source = new EventSource('/live/redis');
} else {
  console.log('SSE not supported');
}

source.addEventListener('open', function (e) {
  console.log('Connection Open');
}, false);
```

I'm using **NodeJS** and **Redis** to get real time messages from the API, but it doesn't matter...

When the **SSE** connection is open I just print a log on the browser.

I do nothing else at moment and if I open my app locally it just work fine and I receive the `console.log` message.

If I push the project on Heroku I don't receive any open connection message.

I can not understand why, probably something is missing or probably do I need to configure Heroku to support SSE?

If I open the project with the command `heroku local` it works fine as well...

**EDIT:**

From the Heroku logs I receive this:

`app/web.1:  GET /live/redis 500 86.403 ms - -`

I can not understand why, locally it is working fine, on Heroku it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

The error is on my Node.js controller for the route `/live/redis` that start with this line:

```
// let request last as long as possible
req.socket.setTimeout(Infinite);
```

Changing it with the line below solved my problem:

```
// let request last as long as possible
req.socket.setTimeout(0x7FFFFFFF);
```

Now I don't know if it is the correct way, but for now it is working.